# Implicit Conversion happening

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

Issue Description:

I am using Springboot 2.7.9 and microsoft sqlserver as database. Spring data Jpa sends BigDecimal datatype as decimal(38,0) to MssqlServer where column is defined as decimal(12,0) which causes implicit conversion during data insertion. Also, implicit conversion is happening for String column which is defined as char(6) in database but jpa is sending it as varchar(8000). Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Entity class column:

```
@Column(name = "APP_ID", precision = 12, scale = 0, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private BigDecimal appId;
```

Database table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[abc](
[ID] [decimal](12, 0) NOT NULL,
[TYP] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[VAL] [decimal](12, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[abc] ADD  CONSTRAINT [X_CROSS_REFERENCE] PRIMARY KEY       CLUSTERED 
( 
[ID] ASC,
[TYP] ASC,
[VAL] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```